# How to center graphics via stylesheet?

Tags: stylesheet, style

I though this should be a simple one, but I have run into issues.
I have a style for Graphics, which holds things like plots generated as outputs from commands, as well as images I may have inserted into a notebook via Insert->Picture->From file..., say. The issue is that I would like those graphics to be *centered relative to other cells*, such as my text cells. However, the graphics come out *centered on the page*, which is off since my text cells are indented. Here are the style definitions I am using:

This is `Text`, for example:

```
Cell[StyleData["Text"],
 CellMargins->{{66, 10}, {7, 7}},
 StyleKeyMapping->{
  "Backspace" -> "Subsubsubsubsection", "Tab" -> "SmallText", 
   KeyEvent["Tab", Modifiers -> {Shift}] -> "Input"},
 CellChangeTimes->{3.61081924778518*^9},
 TextAlignment->Left,
 TextJustification->1.,
 MenuSortingValue->9,
 MenuCommandKey->"4",
 FontFamily->"Source Serif Pro",
 FontSize->12,
 FontWeight->"Plain",
 FontSlant->"Plain",
 FontVariations->{"StrikeThrough"->False,
 "Underline"->False},
 FontProperties->{"ScreenResolution"->Automatic}]
```

Here is my `Graphics` style:

```
Cell[StyleData["Graphics"],
 CellFrame->False,
 TextAlignment->Center,
 TextJustification->0.,
 MenuSortingValue->10000,
 FontFamily->"Source Serif Pro",
 FontSize->12,
 FontWeight->"Plain",
 FontSlant->"Plain",
 FontVariations->{"StrikeThrough"->False,
 "Underline"->False},
 FontProperties->{"ScreenResolution"->Automatic},
 Background->None,
 GraphicsBoxOptions->{ImageSize->600}]
```

I tried simply inserting the line

```
 CellMargins->{{66, 10}, {7, 7}},
```

as the second line of my definition of the `Graphics` style. This works perfectly for images that were manually inserted into the notebook. However, if I try to produce any plots while this style definition is in effect, all hell breaks lose and I end up with lots and lots of error messages. Is there a way to fix the `Graphics` style so it works for both programattically generated graphics as well as images I insert manually? Ot should I just create an additional `Pictures` style, say?